# Radiobuttons through php && mysql, but gives the wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, radio-button

```
<form>
<?php
$stylesheet = array("style_default.css" => "Default", "style_red.css" => "Red");
foreach($stylesheet as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<input type="radio" name="style" value="'.$key.'" checked="';
    if($css == $key){echo 'yes';} else{echo 'no';}
    echo '" /> '.$value.'<br />';
}

?>

    <input type="submit" name="style_change" value="Spara inställningar" />
</form>
```

Here is the code I use to create radio-buttons. On my database I have a table that saves the value of the radio-buttons. I got visual proof on the page that the the path is correct and I have also checked so $css gives the right value with the help of echo.
The value I have is "style_default.css", but I only get the button for red selected. Anyone who knows where all this went wrong?

Comment: It came from a piece of code higher up, among the mysql-code. As I said: I've checked so it gives out the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$css = "style_default.css"; //assumption
$stylesheet = array("style_default.css" => "Default", "style_red.css" => "Red");
foreach($stylesheet as $key => $value){
    echo '<input type="radio" name="style" value="'.$key.'" '; echo ($css == $key)? 'checked>' : '">'; echo $value.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Now they are both blank, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The `checked` attribute accepts only `checked` and an empty string as its value.  For example: `checked="checked"` or `checked=""` are correct.